# How can I use Remark with Astro to make my posts written in markdown preserve the styling?

Tags: markdown, astrojs, remarkjs

I have a blog written in Astro and I write my posts in markdown.
I'm having troubles using remark and remark-html to pass my md tags (such as ##) when I render the post.

```js
async function remarkContent(content) {
    const file = await remark()
        .use(remarkHtml)
        .process(content);
    return content;
}
```

I have tried this function and then pass it to an Html fragment but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Astro has [built-in support for Markdown files and remark](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/markdown-content/), so if your content is in your project folder, you can either place Markdown files in your `src/pages/` and have them automatically transformed into pages or place your files elsewhere, `src/content/` for example, and import them for rendering.

If your content is stored remotely and you are fetching it, you may still need to do something like your example function.

I think the main issue with your example code is that it returns `content`. It should return the *transformed* file instead:

```js
async function remarkContent(content) {
    const file = await remark()
        .use(remarkHtml)
        .process(content);
    return String(file);
}
```

You could then use this in an Astro comment using [the `set:html` directive](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#sethtml):

```
<Fragment set:html={remarkContent(mdString)} />
```

Comment: It does not returns the markdown text formatted correctly...

Comment: Can you provide some more information about what you expect to happen and what actually is happening?

Comment: I want to display the format I used with MarkDown such as # title ## as subtitle ecc...
But it does not working